# Quelle est la prononciation correcte de « pape » ?

Tags: prononciation, étymologie

J'entends souvent le mot *pape* prononcé « pâpe » à la télévision ou à la radio (française et belge).  Pourtant le *a* de pape est court.  Quelle est la prononciation correcte de ce mot ?  Est-ce qu'il y a une origine étymologique ?  Quel est le lien — s'il y en a un — avec le mot anglais *pope* pour lequel le *o* est accentué ?

(Lorsque j'entends *pape*, cela ressemble plus au *pâpe* qu'au [*pape* de l'IPA](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pape).)

Comment: Juste par curiosité: qu'est-ce qui te fait dire que "le 'a' de Pape est court"? Je ne connais pas vraiment de règle (autre que l'usage) qui permette de dire si une voyelle est courte ou longue... (et sinon: oui, je dirais que le 'a' de pape est long en français... A priori le seul lien avec 'pope' est celui d'une origine commune: πάππας en grec, puis *papa* en latin).

Comment: J'ai adapté la question en espérant qu'elle exprime ce que je veux dire.

Comment: Bizarrement le CNRTL ne nous est d'aucune utilité vu qu'il donne la même prononciation pour patte et pâte. http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/patte http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/pâte

Comment: @Joubarc: disparition de la distinction **ɑ/a**. Le TLF donne les prononciations “classiques”, marquant la distinction. Voir ma réponse…

Comment: Au temps pour moi, je regardais dans la section morphologie, j'ignorais que la prononciation se trouvait aussi dans la lexicographie. Donc oui, comme "patte" et pas comme "pâte".

Answer (score 11):

Le *a* de *pape* est en effet **court** : le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pape) donne la prononciation comme *[pap]* (ce qui contraste, par exemple, avec le *a* long de [*mare*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mare) : *[mɑ:ʀ]*.

En résumé :

- pape : courte et antérieure (antérieure = comme *patte*)
- mare : longue et postérieure (postérieure = comme *pâte*)

La distinction entre antérieures et postérieures étant [en train de disparaître](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais) du français parlé pour les *a* (voyelles ouvertes), la longueur tend à devenir la seule différence.

Comment: C'est peut-être mon oreille, mais je n'entend aucune différence dans le français courant (mettons, dans un reportage télé) entre les 'a' de "la venue du pape" et "il est tombé dans la mare"...

Comment: @Dave: je viens de poser une [question sur ce point](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/522)

Comment: Pour moi, *patte* et *pâte* sont aussi différents que *cot* et *caught* en anglais, et je doute que je vais changer. Ça va être un peu triste quand ces distinctions disparaissent complètement.

Comment: @F'x: note que je ne faisais en aucun cas référence à 'pattes' vs 'pâtes' (je pense aussi qu'il y a une différence, même si faible et tendant à s'amenuiser). En substance, je disais plutôt que j'entends 'pape' avec un "a long" (comme dans 'mare') presque tous le temps.

Comment: Par exemple, je dirais qu'il existe une différence de longueur claire entre le 'a' de 'papet' (cf. Pagnol etc.) et celui de 'pape'...

Comment: @Dave: D'expérience, un grand nombre des gens qui commentent les reportages télés (du moins, le JT) ont une moins bonne élocution que le « Français moyen » car ils font des efforts qui exacerbent leur incompétence en lecture… Ça ne m'étonne donc pas, mais je trouve l'argument non pertinent.

Comment: @Axioplase: je ne suis pas tout à fait sûr de à qui tu fais référence (je parle de journaliste de télévision, voire de radio), mais je pense que, toute appréciation personnelle mise-à-part, leur statut de professionnel de la langue parlée *et* leur influence sur la pratique du "Fançais moyen", en font des points de référence importants, du point de vue de la linguistique descriptiviste.

Answer (score 4):

Pour autant que je sois capable de m'observer, ma prononciation de « pape » utilise un a plus long que celui de « patte » mais plus court que celui de « pâte » ou de « mare ».

J'ai par ailleurs dans mon vocabulaire un mot (vraisemblablement un belgicisme, ma femme en tout cas ne le connaissait pas la première fois que je l'ai employé devant elle) qui s'écrit aussi « pape » (merci Joubac pour la [référence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pape), c'est le deuxième onglet) mais que je prononce avec un a très court comme celui de « patte » signifiant en gros « bouillie ».

Comment: La pape s'écrit aussi avec un seul p, voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pape (deuxième onglet). Ça m'a surpris aussi.

Comment: j'ai aussi ce mot dans mon vocabulaire ("bouillie") mais je l'écris avec 2 "p".

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec, qu'on me corrige si j'ai tort, on prononce court le « A » de « pape », je n'ai d'ailleurs jamais entendu le mot « pape » prononcé avec un A long.
J'aimerais avoir l'avis d'autres Québécois(e)s.

Comment: Un autre avis québécois puisque vous le demandez: j'ai toujours entendu «pape» avec un «a» court.