# « Patte » contre « pâte » : qui fait encore la différence ?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, évolution, accents-régionaux

La différence de prononciation entre **patte** (*voyelle* a *antérieure*) et **pâte** (*voyelle* a *postérieure*) tend à disparaître, [nous dit-on](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais). C'est vrai qu’elle n’est pas très marquée chez beaucoup de locuteurs, y compris moi-même, mais j'ai quand même l’impression de la faire (et je pense pouvoir dire, sur une dizaine de mots, lesquels ont [a] et [ɑ].

La question est donc : **dans quelle mesure cette distinction est-elle faite ?** Est-ce que cela correspond à des limites géographies (régionalismes), sociales (un trait de langage pris à un certain niveau d'éducation), ou que sais-je encore ?

PS : C'est une question que je me suis posée par le passé, et qui m’est rappelée par la [question sur la prononciation de « pape »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/515/quelle-est-la-prononciation-correcte-de-pape/519#519).

Edit pour plus de clareté : **je ne parle pas de la longueur**, mais du son produit.

Comment: Belgique: une différence de longueur est faite. Dans le même ordre d'idées, ma femme me frappe quand je prononce _diplôme_ avec un `o` court. Cela dit, pourquoi une question séparée?

Comment: @Joubarc Une question séparée de quoi ? De celle sur *pape* ? Parce que c'est pas vraiment la même question (celle sur *pape* concerne la longueur, j'ai juste rajouté l'info complète tant que j'y était).

Comment: De celle sur _pape_, oui. Je pensais que celle-ci portait sur la longueur aussi, vu que c'est comme ça que j'entends la différence. Du coup, non, je n'entends pas un son différent entre _pâte_ et _patte_, juste une longueur différente. Mais je n'ai pas l'oreille musicale :-)

Comment: Je me force à la faire (par choix et goût), mais dans mon entourage, peu la font.

Comment: "Donne ta pa-patte" dit le maître à son chien. C'est une expression familière qui demande au chien de mettre sa patte dans la main de son maître, c'est  est une succession de trois *a fermés* : `ta-pa-pat`. Une publicité "Des pâtes des pâtes, oui mais des ..." c'est deux *a ouverts* : `pɑ:t`

Comment: @F'x: Je viens du canton de vaud en suisse, et la différence est très marquée. Le 'â' de *pâte* est plus long et plus ouvert, c'est un son complétement différent du 'a' de *patte*, court et fermé.

Comment: Je ne savais même pas qu'il y avait une différence de prononciation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Il y a encore en français métropolitain contemporain une différence entre le "a" de patte et celui de pâte.

Au delà de la simple longueur puisque selon moi pâte se prononce [pɑ:t]."manger des pâtes" ou [pɑt] "pâte à papier", il y a bien une différence de position de la langue.

En effet, si on prononce pâtes, puis que l'on prononce ensuite "patte", on sent bien que le passage de "â" à "a" fait avancer la langue et le maxillaire inférieur.

C'est également sensible dans une courte phrase "avec élan".

- [ty.vwɑ.sɛ.pɑ:t] tu vois ses pâtes
- [ty.vwɑ.sɛ.pat] tu vois ses pattes

Par contre en **Belgique**, le /ɑ/ évolue en [a:]. C'est à dire qu'il y a une double évolution:

- en profondeur(quality) : disparition du /ɑ/ postérieur au profit du /a/ antérieur.
- en longueur : le /a/ correspondant issu d'un /ɑ/ est paraît-il plus allongé.

Ce qui donne :

- [ty.vwɑ.sɛ.pa:t] tu vois ses pâtes?
- [ty.vwɑ.sɛ.pat] tu vois ses pattes?

Il y a peut être d'autres régionalismes mais celui du français de Wallonie est bien documenté.

**Cas de l'Ile de France**

On ne peut cependant pas exclure que la différence soit par contre accentuée en Ile de France. Dans son livre en Anglais "The Sounds of French: An Introduction" (Cambridge UP 1987) [Bernard Tranel](http://www.faculty.uci.edu/profile.cfm?faculty_id=2424) écrit:

> Even though the front [a] (patte [pat] 'paw') resembles English [æ] (cat [kæt]) and even though the back [ɑ] (pâte [pɑt] 'dough') resembles English [ɑ] (father [fɑðər]), the two French vowels generally tend to be more central than the English vowels and thus closer to each other from both an articulatory and a perceptual point of view. **It is, however, interesting to note that in some dialects, particularly in a (stigmatized) variety of Paris French, these two vowels tend to grow apart, [a] becoming more front and slightly less open ([æ]) and [ɑ] becoming rounded ([ɒ])**; hence the following pronunciations, for example: Paris [pari] becomes [pæri], pas [pɑ] 'not' becomes [pɒ]. (Tranel 1987, p. 48)

**Références sur le net**

- [Belgian French phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_French#Phonology).
- [Prononciation du français en Belgique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais#En_Belgique).

Comment: Merci pour ces explications. Chez moi, le son `[ɑ]` n'existe pas, je ne fais vraiment aucune différence (contrairement à `/ɛ̃/` et `/œ̃/` que je ressens comme des phonèmes distincts même si je ne marque pratiquement pas la différence). Apparemment je parle un français non conventionnel.

Comment: @Gilles, il se peut toutefois que ce soit l'inverse ! L'accent parigot ça existe aussi.  J'ai rajouté un paragraphe sur ce sujet.

Comment: Je rajouterais l'accent distingué ou hautain qu'on peut trouver dans des caricatures d'aristocrates.

Answer (score 13):

Je vis au Québec, et la distinction entre *patte* et *pâte* est clairement faite par la très grande majorité des Québécois. En fait, avant l'un de mes cours de phonétique au collégial, je  n'avais jamais entendu que cette distinction tendait à disparaître dans certaines parties de la francophonie. La même constatation nous avait été faite à propos de *brun* et *brin*.

Je dirais donc que la distinction se fait (ou ne se fait pas) de façon majoritairement régionale. Je ne peux me prononcer au sujet d'autres sociétés francophones, mais la distinction est définitivement faite par la majorité des Québécois.

Answer (score 7):

La tendance générale en France voudrait que la différence entre les deux [a] s'amenuise, je l'ai souvent entendu dans mes cours de linguistique.

Dans la pratique, régionalisme aidant (je viens de Normandie), je ne fais pas distinction entre les deux, comme je suis le plus souvent incapable de distinguer les [e].

Je constate d'ailleurs que si les gens remarquent souvent que je prononce mal les [e], ils ne s'étonnent jamais des [a]. Si cette distinction existe donc toujours, elle n'est pas d'une importance capitale pour la plupart des locuteurs que j'ai pu rencontrer.

Answer (score 6):

Ça dépend beaucoup des régions.

En tant que Lorrain, je t'assure que dans l'Est au moins la différence est encore prononcée (jeu de mot…)

Même chose entre autres pour *notre* vs. *nôtre*, *pourrai* vs. *pourrais*, et sans doute d'autres que j'oublie.

Comment: Je suis lorrain aussi et j'ai été incapable "d'entendre" la différence entre /ɑ/ et /a/ parmi les exemples proposés. En revanche, j'ai toujours été pleinement conscient de la différence de longueur entre *pâte* et *patte* et je les prononce très différemment.

Answer (score 5):

Je fais une différence de longueur mais pas de prononciation (et ma femme qui elle est du sud ne la fait pas non plus)

Quant aux autres différences de prononciation, je fais la différence entre o ouvert et fermé (par exemple entre « les eaux » et « les os ») — que ma femme ne fait pas — et entre « brin » et « brun » — que ma femme fait aussi.

Answer (score 5):

Je trouve cet après-midi une ressource dont j'avais oublié l'existence et qui donne un exemple  de prononciation de différents mots (dont [*patte*](http://swac-collections.org/search.php?str=patte&lang=fra) et [*pâte*](http://swac-collections.org/search.php?str=p%C3%A2te&lang=fra)) : le [projet Shtooka](http://swac-collections.org/overview.php?lang=fra). On entend une faible différence entre les deux mots dans ces enregistrements.

---

Answer (score 5):

Il me semble que la distinction n'est pas vraiment faite dans le sud-est de la France. Je prononce de la même façon pâte et patte, comme la majorité de mon entourage. Le contexte primant sur le reste…

Answer (score 3):

Je fais une claire différence de prononciation, particulièrement sur la longueur du a.

Answer (score 3):

Cette question me surprend, puisque, au Nouveau-Brunswick (seule province officiellement bilingue au Canada), tous prononcent ces deux mots d'une façon différente. Je suis allée à une université francophone du N.-B., et tous les étudiants que j'y ai rencontrés, avec leurs différents accents régionaux, prononçaient ces deux mots différemment. Certains étudiants mélangeaient l'anglais et le français quand ils parlaient (le chiac), d'autres parlaient l'ancien français de France en tant qu'Acadiens et d'autres parlaient le québécois, mais tous prononçaient ces deux mots différemment. C'est la même situation dans la capitale du N.-B., où se retrouvent des francophones de toutes les régions du N.-B. Ils prononcent tous ces deux mots différemment. Alors, je peux confirmer que les gens du N.-B. font encore nettement la différence.

Comment: Liens pour accompagner: [chiac](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiac), [français acadien](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_acadien), [Shédiac](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C3%A9diac), [franglais](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franglais).

Answer (score 0):

Je suis souvent surpris en regardant les films d'après-guerre que les "a" n'étaient pas prononcés de la même façon qu'aujourd'hui. Tous les "a"s.