# Le son [a] aujourd'hui

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

**Femme, flamme, poêle, âme.**

Le son [a] est-il le même dans ces mots à nos jours ou existe-t-il encore la différence entre a postérieur et a antérieur ? Les écoliers en appennent-ils à l'école primaire ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [« Patte » contre « pâte » : qui fait encore la différence ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/522/patte-contre-p%c3%a2te-qui-fait-encore-la-diff%c3%a9rence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Pour ce qui est de l’existence ou non de la distinction, les différentes réponses à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/522/patte-contre-p%c3%a2te-qui-fait-encore-la-diff%c3%a9rence) en dressent un bon panorama contemporain.</sub>

---

Pour l’enseignement à l’école, je parlerai en tant que québécois et parent. La distinction à l’oral est ici omniprésente, tout le monde la fait. Mais d’une façon surprenante, parmi les trucs que l’on montre aux enfants pour distinguer les homophones, il y en a concernant « à » ([a]) et « a » ([ɑ]), ainsi que « la » ([la]) et « là » ([lɑ]).

Quand je vais aider à certaines activités et que je tombe sur ces trucs, je dis aux enfants que les distinctions sont faciles, puisqu’elles s’entendent, mais je me heurte systématiquement à un mur d’incompréhension. Les enfants **font** la distinction lorsqu’ils parlent, mais ne semblent pas l’entendre lorsque vient le temps de lire ou d’écrire.

Serait-ce un symptôme d’une trop grande séparation en notre langue de l’oral et de l’écrit ? J’en suis à me le demander.

...Sincèrement ! Quand j’observe les enfants des premières années de scolarisation s’amuser, je les entends dire...

- « Il a joué à la marelle là ! » → [jɑ.ʒwe.aː.ma.ʁɛl.lɑ]

...et lorsqu’ils lisent la même phrase, on les entend prononcer plutôt...

- « Il a joué à la marelle là. » → [il.a.ʒue.a.la.ma.ʁɛl.la]

La fossé entre la lecture et la vraie vie me semble immense.